# confirm new url open in the same window frame (selenium)

Tags: url, selenium, ide, window, verify

is there a way to verify the new URL that open in the same window frame?
the scenario is:
after finish registration Form and click on 'CONTINUE' button, the exist URL:
http://www.example.com/en/registration/en.com  is changing to http://www.example.com/en/cashierfirstdeposit.com (stay on the same window).
when i trying to use verify Location it's fail.
(im using selenium IDE).
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML attributes like `target="_blank"` to make sure that URLs open in a new window every time user clicks on it.

If you don't want the user to open it in new window or want to open it in same window leave it as such.

Comment: the new page is open on the same window frame after the user click on continue, i just trying to verify if the url that open is the correct one.